# Implementing Token Based authentication in jasper?

Tags: single-sign-on, jasperserver

I am new to jasper. I have my web application(has credentials stored in say webAppDB) where i am planning to integrate Jasper server as Single Sign on(SSO). I am going through [sper Authentication cookbook](http://community.jaspersoft.com/system/files/restricted-docs/jasperreportsserver-auth-cookbook_2.pdf)
and found  Token Based authentication can be a good option.

I have few doubts on this. Here are they :-

A) I will be passing the user name and role as part of request to to jasper server(JS) where it will validate the
credentials. My question is from which source JS will validate the credentials. (I mean as credentials are stored in webAppDB , how jasper server
will them)?

B) As per my understanding i need to create internal role along with predefined permissions at jasper server side where administrator will map the roles coming
from webApp with internal roles. Now when resquest is coming from webapp, jasper will get permissions thru External role >Internal Role > permission.
If valid permission is found, access will be given. Is that correct?

Comment: A) In token based authentication, jasper will not validate the username you are passing. It is like a sso where your application validates the user and then sends a request to jasper if user is valid.

Comment: B) yes, jasper validates with the predefined roles.

Answer (score 0):

Token Based Authentication

If you have an application or portal you want to use with JasperReports Server but do not have an existing single sign-on environment, you can use the Jaspersoft token-based authentication and user management framework. To work with token-based authentication.

You can find more information in below link.

https://github.com/mehulkatara/Jasper-Token-based-Authentication